# select2 with AJAX not autocomplete

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm use select2  in my website. In my server side with AJAX/json, I got right response , but it can't auto-complete when I enter letters in that select box,I had facing that problem

[image: First picture]

and that's what I hope:

[image: Second picture]

Here my **HTML** code

```
<input type="hidden" name="region" id="region" style="width:250px;"  />
```

js code:

```
    function format(data){
    return data.text;
};

    $("#region").select2({
    formatResult: format,
    formatSelection: format,
    ajax: {
        url: "/wine/select2.php?country=USA",
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
            q: term 
            };
        },
        results: function (data)
        {
            return { results: data};
        },
        dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop"
    }
});
```

So what's wrong with my code? please guide me how to solve this

Comment: When you use ajax the results you are getting just depend on the search logic you are using on the server side, so if you dont get the expected results you would have to debug you server side search logic. If you just would like to underline the matched characters i think you would have to write your own `formatResult`-function.

Comment: Spaces in urls are bad. Some servers will just omit all data after first space. Encode your url.

Comment: @Tommi  I hidden the truly url.

Comment: There is an example of how you can do the server side logic (with PHP) here: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/wiki/PHP-Example

Comment: Hello, Did u get the solution? I'm facing the same problem..please help!